# Database structure for social login implementation?

Tags: php, mysql

In my application, I have a "user" table that has the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `banned` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `admin` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `signup_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `resetpassword_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

I want to implement social login via Facebook, Twitter, and OpenID in my application, just like Stack Overflow did.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would suggest that you introduce the concept of an `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuthenticationProvider` (
`ProviderKey` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ProviderType` enum('facebook','twitter', 'google') NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY  (`ProviderKey`) )  
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Each login provider provides a unique key for the user. This is stored in `ProviderKey`. The `ProviderType` contains information about which login provider this `ProviderKey` belongs to, and finally, the `userId` column couples the information with the `users` table. So when you receive a succesful login from one of the login providers you find the corresponding `ProviderKey` in the table and use set the authentication cookie for the user in question.

I'm not sure that you want the `ProviderType` to be an `enum`. It would probably be more correct to make another table that could hold these.

When a user first registers with your site, and logs in via Facebook, for example, you will have to create a row in the `users` table. However, there will be no `password`, `activation_key` and `resetpassword_key` involved. So you may want to move those fields to a separate table, such that your `users` table only contains the core user data, and no data that is only relevant for a single login mechanism (username/password).

I hope this makes sense and that it points you in the right direction.

/Klaus

Comment: What if user from Facebook and Twitter has same key?

Comment: ProviderType can be used to differentiate them

Comment: @EjazKarim, these keys are not sequencial, so if Twitter's database has the same key for a user as Facebook's database, I think we can start to run.

Comment: upvoted, which ones would you create an index on? i guess when a person tries to login, you want to check if their facebook id already exists, if it does, then simply create them with their details and add their id and token, if it does not exist then create a new user, set their facebook id and update their primary email with the emall you get from facebook api